# Is there a version of the flag of Pakistan which uses black instead of green?

Tags: pakistan, flag

I'm trying to figure out if this is a case of really bad color rendering, or is there a version of the flag of Pakistan that uses black instead of (dark) green. Image [from](https://www.france24.com/en/asia-pacific/20220407-pakistan-top-court-rules-against-khan-over-dissolving-parliament) Reuters.

[image]

The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Pakistan) on the flag of Pakistan doesn't mention any black version. Nor is there anything like that listed in the [list of related flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pakistani_flags). So what explains the black color?

Comment: On my screen, to my eyes, that flag definitely looks green. A *very* dark green, to be fair, but still noticeably green.

Comment: (The raw RGB colors of the flag in the image actually have hues ranging from cyan to blue. But [in context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_constancy) it certainly looks green to me.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, it’s just an odd colour balance in that particular image - see another angle from the same event [from Alamy](https://www.alamy.com/pakistans-prime-minister-imran-khan-and-his-sri-lankan-counterpart-mahinda-rajapaksa-talk-at-the-end-of-the-trade-and-investments-conference-during-khans-two-day-visit-in-colombo-sri-lanka-february-24-2021-reutersdinuka-liyanawatte-image408197595.html):

[image]

Comment: Compare also the name tags on the table.  That similarly lost its green in the OP's image.  Though the label on the water bottle managed to keep some color, but even that is noticeably darker.

Answer (score 0):

Green is meant to represent the country's Muslims; green is supposed to be a colour of peace in Pakistan's culture. There is no black colour. Most people in Pakistan use black colour to stay away from "bad eyes", and it is just a bad picture from the wrong angle.